# Call LUIS outside of MessageController and after Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Working on a Bot that authenticates using ADAL (AuthBot) and then post-Auth takes the user input and sends to LUIS to gather intents/entities.  I use what's returned to build a URI that I send to Sharepoint Online REST API.  If user input is valid, Sharepoint returns JSON that I parse and return to user.

The trouble is getting the user input to my LUIS class after authentication.  I call AuthBot ActionDialog from my MessageController.

```
        if (message.Type == "Message")
        {
            return await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new ActionDialog());
        }
```

Within ActionDialog, I'm not sure how to move move the Message to the LUIS Class

```
   public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Message> item)
    {
        var message = await item;
        if (message.Text == "logon")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(await context.GetAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"])))
            {
                await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"]), this.ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(await context.GetAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"])))
        {
            await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"]), this.ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            //this is where I want to send the next user input from bot to LUIS class.                
        }
    }
```

The LUIS Class is standard and looks like this:

```
//Define the LuisModel that will be used.  The LuisModel JSON file can be found at ~/json/letseat.json
[LuisModel("ModelID", "ModelSecret")]
[Serializable]
public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
```

Any Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using [AuthBot](https://github.com/matvelloso/AuthBot) (by looking at the code).

What you need to add is the following:

```
 await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
```

That will just pass the message to LUISDialog's MessageReceived implementation; which will issue a query to LUIS to understand which intent should be executed.

Comment: Thanks Ejadib.  Assuming you mean to place the MessageReceived line in my LUIS Class, correct?

Comment: @EzequielJadib where should that line be? In the beginning of intent methods? Also how does it work?

Comment: In the MessageReceivedAsync if you overrided that method

Comment: @EzequielJadib Any chance you could put a code sample for both the Luis and the ActionDialog classes? It would make it clearer.