# How to call a LUIS Dialog outside of the MessagesController class

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to call a LUIS dialog from outside of MessagesController class. I create a root Dialog in my MessageController class:

```
 if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message) {
 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MessageDialogHandler());
```

In my MessageDialogHandler class I'm handling Attachments and Text input.

```
if (activity.Attachments?.Count() > 0) {
            FaceAnalysis faceAnalysis = new FaceAnalysis();
            await faceAnalysis.AnalyseImageAsync(context, argument);
        }
else if(activity.Text.Length > 0) {
//here needs to be the code to call a LUIS dialog.
}
```

I have a standard LUIS class:

```
[LuisModel("App-ID", "SubscriptionKey")]
[Serializable]

public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object> {
```

How do I manage to call that LUIS Dialog from my MessageDialogHandler class?
Yes I did read this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010375/call-luis-outside-of-messagecontroller-and-after-authentication) but it didn't help me.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a context.Forward of the message to the LuisDialog.

```
await context.Forward(
      new LuisDialog(), 
      LuisDialogCompleted, 
      activity, 
      System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
```

To understand more around how to call dialogs, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465).